# LEFT JOIN перезаписывает переменную $id, почему?

Tags: php, join

Почему и в какой момент перезаписывается `$id` и как этого избежать, всё так же ища по id, а не по другому признаку.

Есть таблица пользователей *users* и таблица статусов *statuses*. Каждый пользователь - 1 (юзер), либо 2 (админ).
В следующем примере mysqli_query выдаст пустоту:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = "SELECT users.id, users.login, users.name, users.status_id, statuses.name as statusesLK
            FROM users
            LEFT JOIN statuses ON statuses.id=users.status_id
            WHERE id = '$id'";
```

А вот если искать не по ID, а по логину - то всё ок. Почему? В какой момент и почему перезаписывается и как этого избежать и искать по ID?

```
$log = $_SESSION['login'];
$query  = "SELECT users.login, users.name, users.status_id, statuses.name as statusesUniqName
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN statuses ON statuses.id=users.status_id
    WHERE login='$log'";
```

Comment: Что значит перезаписывается $id? Просто по кускам Вашего кода видно, что значение $id задаётся только один раз, и более не меняется.

Comment: Хм, возможно я неверно понял проблему...
Расскажу свои мысли и наблюдения.
При логине записываю в сессию $_SESSION['id'] и $_SESSION['login']. 
Затем чтобы в определённом месте на странице отображался "логин-статус". Но вот если искать по Where id = '$id' - запрос возвращается пустой, а по Where login = '$log' - запрос возвращается как надо.

Понимаю, что по-хорошему при логине записать нужную информацию в сессию и не мучать БД, но у меня в процессе обучения уже несколько раз такая проблема возникала, очень хочу разобраться почему по Where = $id не возвращается результат

Comment: *LEFT JOIN перезаписывает переменную $id* Если сам вопрос ещё туда-сюда, то его сабж - ну полный бред. Сервер БД и всё с ним связанное вообще, и уж тем более LEFT JOIN в тексте запроса, в принципе никак и никогда не способны изменить значения в PHP-переменной.

Comment: У вас поле `id` есть в обеих таблицах? Может, в первом запросе нужно уточнить, из какой таблицы `id` должен равняться `$id` ?

Comment: Да, br3t, спасибо! Запрос не понимал, какой из id должен равняться $id. Спасибо!
$query = "SELECT users.id, users.login, users.name, users.status_id, statuses.name as statusesLK
         FROM users
          LEFT JOIN statuses ON statuses.id=users.status_id
         WHERE users.id = '$id'";